# Android - Get touch point coordinates relative to zoomed image

Tags: android, image, canvas, marker

I'm looking for the best way(s) of getting the position of a point I touched on an image and get it's coordinates relative to the image size.

For example, I get, as the parent image, the map of a building floor. And the user need to be able to zoom in and point on the map a point that will be registered in a database in order to be retreived later.

I never really had to work with images and canvases on Android so I'm a bit confused. What might be the best approach. I already found a lot of document but couldn't find one that would fit the idea I need to develop.

Thanks in advance for you help,
Matthieu

Comment: In most cases Zoom is a result of applied Matrix transformation on canvas. When user click on image you can get touch position in client control coordinates or screen coordinates.

use the same transformation matrix for for re-calculating touch coordinates to image coordinates. (its depends on logic that you want to implement). 

Short answer: just use the Matrix for converting the coordinates of touches to image

Comment: @Oleksandr Kucherenko I'll look into this thank you :)

Comment: @pskink actually to zoom on an image I'm using this class https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/blob/master/src/com/ortiz/touch/TouchImageView.java by Mike Ortiz which get me my zoomed image and the center of the zoom relative to the image. Now when I touch the image I need to calculate the point relative to my parent image with the coordinate of the center of my zoom :)

Comment: then use `getImageMatrix` method

Comment: @pskink yes but how do I use it? I don't understand :/

Comment: see `Matrix#mapPoints` method

Comment: Thanks you :)  I'll see if I'll figure out how to do it :D